# Icons take several seconds to appear/disappear from the dock when the app is opened/closed

Tags: nvidia, gnome-shell, 20.04, ubuntu-dock

When opening and closing an application, there is a delay of up to 30 seconds before that icon appears or disappears from the dock. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. It occurs when running both free (Nouveau) & proprietory Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I think I have the same issue. Does it temporarily go to "no" delay if you restart with "alt" + "F2" -> "r" -> "enter"? I tried to find what is causing the problem and so far, getting the dock into the state of no icons (besides the "Show Applications" button) triggered the behavior reliably for me so far. Same for you? I opened a issue here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1880570

Answer (score 1):

If your dock is empty besides the "Show Applications" button, the delayed/missing update of icons in the dock is most probably caused by https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/1188 and will be fixed by https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/pull/1222 . A bug report for the ubuntu version of the dock is tracked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1880570

Answer (score 0):

mine was bc of a slow SD card in my laptop card reader (does that seem possible?)
as if it was taking time to read the card and populate the icon for the external drive. finally booted with a different card in there, and icons are updating in real time

shortcut to launch icons, if you can't fix your problem, is windows-button + the number of the icon in the list, so i could always launch firefox with windows+1 upon startup, before the icons showed up